# White Lotus Master Riposte and AOE at wills

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, attack

The feat White Lotus Master Riposte reads:

> Prerequisites: 11th level, any arcane class, White Lotus Riposte feat
>   Benefit: When an enemy you hit with an arcane at-will attack power attacks you before the start of your next turn, you can repeat the at-will attack power’s attack against that enemy as an immediate reaction.

How would this work with an AoE such as an Elementalist's Ice Prison or Blazing Cloud. do you get free hits on any extra enemies that happens to be in the aoe since the attack gets repeated?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, doesn't look like you do.

In the [July 2010 Errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdateJuly2010.pdf), WotC printed this regarding White Lotus Master Riposte.

> Dragon 374
>   White Lotus Master Riposte, page 21
>   Replace the feat’s Benefit entry with the following
>   text:
>
> > “If you hit an enemy with an arcane at-will
> >     attack power and the enemy then attacks you before
> >     the start of your next turn, you can use an immediate reaction to repeat the at-will attack against that enemy alone, but only if the enemy is not marked by
> >     you.”
>
> This change prevents a Catch-22 with swordmage marking. It also allows a character to target only the attacker if he or she uses a close or area at-will arcane power. In other words, even if other creatures are in the area of effect of a close or an area attack, the power targets only the triggering enemy."

So you would only be able to hit the enemy that attacked you.

Answer (score 6):

**The riposte is not AoE.**

Note the wording of the feat (*emphasis mine*):

> ...you can repeat the at-will attack power's attack against *that enemy* as an immediate reaction.

You repeat the at-will power's attack but with the Target line for the power effectively changed to "the triggering creature".

The advantage of using White Lotus Master Riposte with an AoE power is that you can trigger the riposte if *any* of the targets you hit attacks you (but only 1 riposte per round, since it uses your immediate reaction). The AoE makes it more likely that at least one target will choose to attack you and that you will thus get to make the riposte.